# AddValidation to IConfiguration.Bind .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

In .NET Core 2.2 we can do this

```
services.AddOptions<EventsSettings>()
        .Bind(configuration.GetSection("Settings"))
        .ValidateDataAnnotations();
```

I am trying not to rely on `IOptions` for DI, so I have the following:

```
var settings = new EventsSettings();
configuration.Bind("Settings", settings);

services.AddSingleton(settings);
```

This works great, but now I want to add validation to my settings for the second option, but I see that IConfiguration.Bind doesnt have any way to add validation check.

The `IOptionBuilder` has the needed steps but not sure how to apply it without using the .`AddOptions`

Comment: Provided an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54990629/5233410) that does not require you to use `AddOptions`

Comment: I saw that, thank you but i iwent with the one that did use AddOptions since it does all the valuation and i do not rely on IOptions in my controllers

Comment: Ok. I thought you were trying to avoid `IOptions`.

Comment: @Nkosi I was trying to avoid relying on IOptions in my controllers etc that was what was important. I, perhaps could have made my initial post more clearer, thanks for the answers though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could leave it like it is and register the `EventsSettings`

```
  services.AddOptions<EventsSettings>()
                .Bind(Configuration.GetSection("Settings"))
                .ValidateDataAnnotations();

  // Register the EventsSetting service using the factory overload
  services.AddTransient(srv => srv.GetService<IOptions<EventsSettings>>().Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

The extension method called by the builder uses a custom class that wraps `Validator.TryValidateObject`, which you can use yourself to validate the setting

```
var settings = configuration.GetSection("Settings").Get<EventsSettings>();

//validate
var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
var validationContext = new ValidationContext(settings, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
if (!Validator.TryValidateObject(settings, validationContext, validationResults, 
        validateAllProperties: true)) {
    //...Fail early
    //will have the validation results in the list
}

services.AddSingleton(settings);
```

That way you are not coupled to `IOptions`.

The validation code could be packaged into a extension method for reuse.